# Lucee Error - java.security.cert.CertificateException: No X509TrustManager implementation available

Tags: java, tomcat, ssl, lucee

In converting an ACF website to Lucee, we're facing some configuration issues.  Our environment is Lucee5, Tomcat7, and Java.

There seems to be something not configured correctly for Lucee to be able to access an endpoint webservice via SSL. The same code works without any issues on CF9 on the same sever in a different Tomcat container.

The test call:

```
cfhttp(method="GET", charset="utf-8", url="https://our_lucee_server.org/wf/webservice/wf_webservice.cfc?wsdl", result="result") {
}
writeDump(result);
```

results in a:

```
java.security.cert.CertificateException: No X509TrustManager implementation available
```

---

It's been suggested that the endpoint serving the WSDL is the issue and that either Tomcat or Apache needs to be configured. Since Lucee is the program throwing the error, how can I determine what's preventing Lucee from accessing the endpoint?

The WSDL can be accessed no problem from a browser.

Things we've tried.

- importing the SSL into Lucee from the target domain using Lucee server admin and restarting.
- Spinning up an instance of Lucee using CommandBox, and then copying the cacerts file from CommandBox to the Lucee Server.

Comment: Additionally - making the call to the WSDL URL from a CF9 instance - BOTH CFHTTP requests work fine. When the requests are made from the Lucee instance .... both of them fail.  Shouldn't both fail if there was an issue with the endpoint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the final solution for us was running the following two commands.
this is for a CentOS7, Java 8, Tomcat, Lucee5 set up ...

step 1: back up the lucee keystore:

```
mv /opt/tomcatxxx/webapps/xxxx/WEB-INF/lucee-server/context/security/cacerts /opt/tomcatxxx/webapps/xxxx/WEB-INF/lucee-server/context/security/cacerts.bak
```

(where `/opt/tomcatXXX/webapps/XXX/WEB-INF/` is the path to the lucee instance)

step 2:  make a symbolic link between the java keystore and the lucee keystore

```
ln -s /opt/tomcatxxx/conf/s2s-ubertruststore_01_10_18.jks /opt/tomcatxxx/webapps/xxxx/WEB-INF/lucee-server/context/security/cacerts
```

Essentially, the keystore that came with Lucee5 didn't work out of the box.
Pointing the lucee keystore to the working Java keystore fixed it.

Step 3:
Restart Tomcat and lucee

Answer (score 0):

i think this can be solved by importing the cert for the site you are trying to access and adding it to the java home / jre / lib / security folder ...

for reasons unknown the cert for the site you are trying to access is not trusted so need to add it to trust store.

Comment: I've had that suggested, but it simply isn't the case. Calls made from a CF9 instance on the same box (same TLD) to either WSDL work fine. Calls from Lucee - to the working CF9 instance fail. The problem is with Lucee.

Comment: i found this with the search might help https://dev.lucee.org/t/cant-consume-web-service/1585/8